# Screen rotation for basic window program won't work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I created a very basic iPad application using the "Window-based Application" template. Unfortunately, the provided view will not rotate when I rotate the simulator.

Furthermore, when I add a view controller and/or a UINavigationController to the base window, they won't rotate either. I've implemented

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

in the view controller I added ... but still, can't see any rotation.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you remember to set in the target that all rotations are supported?

Comment: Is your device rotation-locked ?

Comment: You mean you've implemented `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to your view controller, not your view, right?

Comment: @cduhn Correct, sorry for the misleading verbiage in the original post. I added a ViewController with the appropriate method.

Comment: @Shivan this happens in the simulator.

Comment: This issue should be very easy to recreate. In Xcode, File >> New Project >> Window-based Application (Product = iPad). Then run the application and rotate the simulator. Does your rotate? Does it rotate if you add your own view controllers or a UINavigationController? Happens for me in both Xcode 3.2.5 and Xcode 4.0.2.

Comment: @MSgambel Yes, all rotations are selected when I create a new project in Xcode 4.0.2. I don't know where to check such a setting in Xcode 3.2.5. But again, this must be happening for everybody no? There must be a setting or something - I can't believe no one else is seeing this for Window-based Applications. Weird.

Comment: @Luther: I'm seeing the exact same problem, and I still haven't fixed it. I've created a window-based app, and added a ViewController, but nothing that I do will let it rotate to anything other than portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To orchestrate autorotation, your application's window looks for its top-most subview that's managed by a view controller.  The window calls `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` on this view controller, and transforms the view controller's view as directed.

This is why a window based application doesn't autorotate out-of-the-box.  The default template doesn't come with a view controller already set up for you.  To take advantage of autorotation, you must create a custom `UIViewController` subclass, edit its `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method as appropriate, and add that view controller's view as a direct subview of your window (or add the view controller to a container like a `UINavigationController`, and add that container view controller's view as a subview of the window).  This is typically done in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

You state that "when I add a view controller and/or a UINavigationController to the base window, they won't rotate either," and that you've implemented `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, and that it still won't rotate.  This should work if you've configured everything properly.  You probably made some small mistake in this process, but I can't say for sure what it is without seeing your project.  Here are some things to check:

1. If you've defined your custom view controller in a NIB, make sure you remembered to change its Class name on the Identity Inspector in IB.
2. Make sure you're adding the view controller's view directly to the window, and that you don't have some other view acting as a wrapper between your window and your view controller's view.
3. Make sure you're not trying to add any subviews to your Window object in IB.  You should be adding its subview in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.
4. If you've defined your custom view controller in a NIB, make sure its view appears nested under the View Controller in IB.  i.e. Don't try to connect some other view to the view controller's `view` outlet.

Those are some shots in the dark.  Hopefully something in this answer will help you find your mistake.  If not, try creating a view-based application and compare its default configuration to your window-based application.  Maybe then your mistake will jump out at you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ... unfortunately, it isn't working for me. To review the steps I'm taking (1) create Window-based Application for iPad (2) Create very simple class extending UIViewController with only one method, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (3) update didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with 2 lines: RotateMe *rotateMe = [[RotateMe new] autorelease]; and [self.window addSubview:rotateMe.view]; The new view shows up ... but still won't rotate. I will take a look at the 'View' based project.

Comment: I take it that you're building the view hierarchy for RotateMe in RotateMe.xib, right?

Comment: Wait...  It looks like you're declaring `rotateMe` as a local variable.  It's going to get autoreleased after it goes out of scope.  The view is retained as a subview of the window, but the controller is dealloc'd by the time you try to rotate.  You should retain rotateMe as a property of your app delegate.

Comment: That was it! You are the MAN!! and I should have known better. Thanks for your patience!